# why my urlrewrite does not work?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using Tuckey URL Rewrite Filter, ex:

```
<rule>
  <from>^/company/([0-9]+).html</from>
  <to type="forward">/companypreview?id=$1</to>
```

but it does not work~ when I enter the /company/123.html ,it return 404

but I enter the /companypreview?id=123 is return a real page

Comment: Could use some more information here. Presumably `/companypreview?id=123` is a valid page, but it might be nice to check that.

Comment: yes, this is the UrlRewriteFilter